# How to find a local chart on a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let's say that we are given a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let's also say that this is given by some equation $f(x, y, z)=0$. How do I use this to find a chart around some point on my surface?

Let's consider the special case of a hyperboloid of two sheets given by the equation $x^2-y^2-z^2=1$. I could use the equation to express $y$ in terms of $x$ and $z$. We have $y=\pm \sqrt{x^2-z^2-1}$, where the sign is easily determined depending on which sheet of the hyperboloid the point is. But where to go from here?

I suspect that there should be some general method to get an atlas from a parametrization of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ since we know that they are $2$-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The chart map is (on a certain domain) $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,z)$. The inverse map is then $(x,z)\mapsto (x,\sqrt{x^2-z^2-1},z)$ for example. In general, you can't write down 'explicit formulas' like this, but the inverse/implicit function theorem tells you that such maps exist. For this specific function, you can come up with 6 obvious charts (where $x>0$ or $x<0$ or $y>0$(which is what I wrote above) or $y<0$ or $z>0$ or $z<0$).

Comment: To complement peek-a-boo's comment, there are two questions: 1. How to get a chart for an _implicitly-defined surface_ and 2. How to get an atlas from a _parametrization_. Each also hinges on how explicit an answer is sought. The bad news is, if $f$ is "nice" (for example _polynomial_) we cannot hope to find an elementary parametrization (in the technical sense). In practice, one falls back on the implicit function theorem, which only guarantees existence. For the second, a chart is the inverse mapping to a parametrization, but we still can't hope for an elementary mapping.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see, so basically I am taking the chart map $\varphi(x, y, z)=(x, z)$ and I am defining this on the domain on which it is bijective (and for this I am looking at where the inverse $(x, z)\mapsto(x, \sqrt{x^2-z^2-1}, z)$ is well defined), right? Or more directly said, I am looking at where it makes sense to express $y$ as a function of $x$ and $z$.

Comment: @JustAnAmateur yup.